# Upload video to my channel via Youtube API V3 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

To make things more clear:

Account A - The account that i used to create the api credentials and where i have the channel that i want to receive the uploaded videos

Account B - The account that i used to test the video uploading

I reproduced [this example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) from google and replaced the client ID with mine (from Account A). It asks first for authentication (i logged in from Account B) and then i picked up a local video to upload. The result: Uploaded the video to Account B instead of the account A.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ffvo.png)

**How can i make it to upload to Account A?**

I also tried to do it without oauth by **using just an API Key** but without success (i didn't found an example for that ) so if someone can help with this method i'm grateful.

**Note: I will implement this in a wordpress site page, where only users with editor role can access it.**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. From your question I understand that you are logged in as Account B while uploading the video, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that application credentials have nothing to do with your user account right your still going to have to authenticated the application to access YouTube

If you want to upload to account b then login to account b when you're application request access.  If you want to upload to account a then login and authenticate your application to account a.

your application can only upload to the account of the current authenticated user.

Comment: I think i didn't understood what i want with my question... I want to make other specific users to upload videos to my channel. I dont want to share the credentials of account A to them (they would have the full access, which is something that i dont want) to allow them to upload videos for the channel

Comment: you are going to have to authentication your application once save the refresh token and use that to get a new Access token when ever you want to upload to the account.

Comment: So i cant achieve what i want this way with Oauth? And what about API Key?